# CSS to show the last td of each row when hovering on a row, and show the last td of each column when hovering on a column

Tags: css

I have an html table where I want to, using only CSS:

- show the last td of each row when hovering on the row, and
- show the last td of each column when hovering on that column.

This is my solution for rows:

```css
/* Hide last cell in each row by default */

tr td:last-child {
  display: none;
}


/* Show last cell in row on row hover */

tr:hover td:last-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But for the life of me I cannot make it work for columns.

NOTE: Any method to show/hide cells is game (display/visibility, etc)

Comment: @MisterJojo using visibility works for me as well.

Comment: @MisterJojo CSS is simpler if possible.

Comment: @MisterJojo then post an answer explaining/demonstrating why it cannot be done and I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @MisterJojo: it *can*, but it's not fully cross-browser compatible (Firefox, even when `:has()` is enabled via flags) doesn't work with the solution shown by [Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77119919/82548), below. Chrome does, and presumably other browsers also will. JavaScript is, however, far more reliable (and, looking at Ori's solution, far *far* simpler).

Comment: @MisterJojo I know how to solve this with JS.

Comment: @DavidThomas - I agree, and JS more flexible as well, because you don't need a specific rule for each column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) rule (currently not supported by FF) to show the last `td` in a column, if one of the `td` elements in that column id hovered. You'll need to supply a specific rule for each column:

```css
/** rows **/
tr:not(:hover) td:last-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/** column 1 **/
table:not(:has(tr td:nth-child(1):hover))
  tr:last-child td:nth-child(1) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

/** column 2 **/
table:not(:has(tr td:nth-child(2):hover))
  tr:last-child td:nth-child(2) {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you have a large amount of columns, or the number of columns is dynamic, you can generate the rules for the columns using JS:

```js
const generateColumnRules = numOfColumns => {
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.innerHTML = Array.from(
    { length: numOfColumns },  
    (_, i) => `
      table:not(:has(tr td:nth-child(${i + 1}):hover))
        tr:last-child td:nth-child(${i + 1}) {
          visibility: hidden;
        }    
    `
  ).join('\n');
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(style);
}

generateColumnRules(2);
```

```css
/** rows **/
tr:not(:hover) td:last-child {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, regarding your second solution, no JS allowed.

Comment: There are 2 solutions - the 1st one doesn't include JS. The 2nd uses JS to generate the rules.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this with JS code, working on ALL browsers (FireFox doesn't support CSS `:has()`)

Less than ten lines of JS code (and 2 lines of css)

```js
const
  myTable  = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')
, last_TDs = myTable.querySelectorAll('tr:last-child td')
  ;
myTable.onmouseover = ({target:TDx}) =>
  {
  last_TDs.forEach(td => td.classList.remove('showIt'))
  if (!TDx.matches('td')) return;  
  last_TDs[TDx.cellIndex].classList.add('showIt');
  }
myTable.onmouseout = () =>
  {
  last_TDs.forEach(td => td.classList.remove('showIt'))
  }
```

```css
/*-- cosmetic part -- */
table {
  border-collapse  : separate;
  border-spacing   : 1px;
  background-color : darkblue;
  margin           : 1em;
  color            : black;
  font-size        : .8rem;
  --showCol        : 2;
  }
table td {
  background-color : whitesmoke;
  padding          : .2em .6em;
  min-width        : 2em;
  text-align       : right;
  }
/*-- cosmetic part -- [end] */


tr td:last-child       { color: whitesmoke;  }
tr:hover td:last-child { color: black; }

tr:last-child td        { color: whitesmoke;  }
tr:last-child td.showIt { color: black;  }
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <caption> horizontal/vertical sums</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td> 1</td><td> 2</td><td> 3</td><td> 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td> 4</td><td> 5</td><td> 6</td><td>12</td></tr>
    <tr><td> 7</td><td> 8</td><td> 9</td><td>18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>12</td><td>15</td><td>18</td><td>  </td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```